# MultiPostThumbnails and media queries

Tags: plugins, css

I am using the plugin "MultiPostThumbnails" and it's setting my width to 700px.

Is there a way to get it to not set the width and height at all? I want it to resize when I use media queries and instead what is happening is that the image "box" is getting smaller but the image is not because of the width and height settings in the `<img>` tag...

Answer (score 0):

You should try the following plugin: [WP Fluid Images](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-fluid-images/). It removes the fixed width and height of image tags.

Comment: This seemed like a good idea but it does not override the settings in the other plugin.